# Jquery Splitting 2D Array from JSON result

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

### Example JSON_encode result

```
[{"Apparatus":"test123"},{"Equipment":"41324121"},{"Chemical":"314"},{"Apparatus":"4312"},{"Equipment":"134"},{"Chemical":"324"}]
```

I am having a hard time making the json_encode result (From a php page) to turn it to something like this:

```
var data = 
["Apparatus", "test123"],
["Apparatus", "4312"],
["Equipment", "41324121"],
["Equipment", "134"],
["Chemical", "314"],
["Chemical","324"]
```

Edit: and call it later one by one. Thank you.

Edit2: it will be use for pdfmake's table side.
An example of my expected code (For more details: [PDF Make](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted))

```
        body: [
      [ 'Type', 'Data' ],
      appdata_splits
    ]
```

Comment: We're going to have a hard time with it too, as you've not provided and code you've tried and you haven't told us why the output needs to be in the format you're suggesting.

Comment: The output you've suggested isn't valid. I assume you've just missed out the outer `[]` to create the 2D array?

Comment: Update Edits. Hopefully can help with the problem.

Comment: Makes more sense to show the php and fix it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you require you can call `map()` on the original array, which in turn returns an array of the required values. Try this:

```js
var data = [{"Apparatus":"test123"},{"Equipment":"41324121"},{"Chemical":"314"},{"Apparatus":"4312"},{"Equipment":"134"},{"Chemical":"324"}]

var arr = data.map(function(o) {
  var k = Object.keys(o)[0];
  return [k, o[k]];
});
console.log(arr);
```

In the code above `o` represents the object in the original array being iterated over. As the key of the object is dynamic, we have to use the `Object.keys()` method to retrieve an array of them. The `[0]` accessor retrieves the first of these, as it's guaranteed to exist given your sample data. the `o[k]` then retrieves the value from the object via the key we just retrieved.

Comment: I saw that .map() but it's currently hard for me to understand it. I would like an explanation for it.

Comment: I added an explanation of the logic for you. I'd suggest researching the methods on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) if you're still unclear.

Comment: Thanks. will try it when I got home. Edit: The MDN section is too nerdy for me to understand.